# Injecting variables into the caller's scope?

Tags: python, variables, scope

Can I define a function which, when called, inserts new locals into the caller's scope? I have a feeling that passing the caller's *locals()* into the function might work, but is there a way to do what I want *without* having to do this?

Comment: Suppose the caller is expected to understand the risks of the callee going to town with its locals.

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for spaghetti

Comment: It's called "return".

Comment: As usual, there is a use case. Suppose you have a little language which matches an expression against a tree, and binds names to tree nodes. I want a call to the _match_ function to, as a side effect, put those names in the caller's scope.

Comment: This is generally a terrible idea... But it happens that I've wanted to do this too, in a very specific situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Python's rules, you cannot alter your caller's `locals`; in the current implementations, if you try (e.g. with the black magic Anurag suggests) you will not get an exception (though I'd like to add that error check to some future version), but it will be essentially inoperative if your caller is a function (not if your caller is module top-level code) -- the caller's actual local variables won't in fact be affected.  This holds whether the caller's `locals` are explicitly passed in, or fetched through black magic: they still need to be treated as a read-only dict if your code is to have any sanity.

Rather, you could have the caller pass in an explicit, real, normal dict (which could be initialized from `locals()` if you want), and all alterations your code does in that dict will still be there for the caller's use -- just not as "new barenames" in the caller's local scope of course, but the functionality is the same whether the caller needs to use `x['foo']` or `x.foo` or (as you'd prefer) just barename `foo`.

BTW, to use attribute-access syntax rather than dict indexing syntax, you can do:

```
class Bunch(object): pass

...

# caller code
b = Bunch()
thefun(b)
print b.foo

...

# called function
def thefun(b):
  b.foo = 23
```

This also covers, with a tiny variation, the case in which `thefun` wants to work with dict indexing syntax (say its body is `b['foo'] = 23` instead of `b.foo = 23`): in that case, the caller just needs to use `thefun(vars(b))` instead of the plain `thefun(b)`, but it can keep working with the `b.foo` access syntax afterwards.

Comment: Okay, sounds like it's not really possible to do what I want. Thanks for the attribute access idea; if I can't have barenames (x), the next prettiest thing is probably attribute access (context.x).

Comment: This is not true, see the answer below using builtin python's inspect module to see how its done. Python is a complete dynamic language you can overwrite its own interpreter if you so wish. I only quote http://xkcd.com/353/

Comment: Alex is correct. @Pykler's answer only works in one specific case, and not generally.

Comment: Thanks a lot, such a nice solution!

Answer (score 21):

Check out the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html), it is used by [minimock](https://bitbucket.org/jab/minimock/src/b7acbfeadbd2/minimock.py#cl-169) to mock the caller's scope.

This code ought to do what you want exactly:

```
import inspect
def mess_with_caller():
    stack = inspect.stack()
    try:
        locals_ = stack[1][0].f_locals
    finally:
        del stack
    locals_['my_new_function'] = lambda : 'yaaaaaay'


mess_with_caller()
print my_new_function()
>>> Output: 'yaaaaaay'
```

Comment: FYI: inspect is a built in python module.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed for django settings magic.  Quite nice.

Comment: This doesn't work if you call `mess_with_caller` from anything other than top-level module code. Presumably this is because you can modify `f_globals` on the stack frame, but not f_locals, and when you call `mess_with_caller` from top-level code `f_locals == f_globals`. In other words, it'd be more appropriate for `mess_with_caller` to change `f_globals`, because that's the only instance in which it works.

Comment: @ferrouswheel The code as simply as it is written messes with the caller's scope (the previous stack). You are right though that in some cases you may need to use f_globals. Use the minimock code as a reference and you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: @Pykler- he is saying that this does not work when f_locals != f_globals and so you might as well just use f_globals.

See http://ideone.com/dbl1lL

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without changing the API, as CPython retains a reference to the argument list for the duration of the function call.

One way to do this is to pass an object, and clear the object's internal state when done using it.

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state

def f(o):
    # Do stuff with o.state
    del o.state
```