# Returning a Statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating my own code language, and I want to implement a `import` feature for the code. I have my main code, where you code in the language:

```
from config.Bean_Functions import *
impt.math()
print math.sqrt(4)
```

Then, I have a folder in the same directory named `config`, in which I have a file called `Bean_Functions.py`:

```
class impt(object):
    @staticmethod
    def math():
        return from config.Bean_Math import *
```

Then finally, in the `config` folder, I have a file named `Bean_Math.py` and the code for that is:

```
class math(object):
    def sqrt(op1):
        return round(op1 ** 0.5, 2)
```

Now, my question is that I want to return a `from...import...` statement, but Python interprets it as trying to return the process of import the file, but I want it to return the whole *line*.
Any way I can do that?

I am running Python 2.7.10

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What could it mean to "return" a statement?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if I call the `imps.math()` function, I want it to then import all the modules from `Bean_Math`, with out having to type the Python command in the main code

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, you want a function call to bring new names into the local scope?

Comment: `'statimethod' != 'staticmethod'`, for one thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah I noticed that

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want a function that you call to modify the scope of the caller. This isn't do-able, except perhaps with some [extreme hackery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515450/injecting-variables-into-the-callers-scope), and even if it is, you'll be better off structuring your program in a way which doesn't rely on that.

You talk about creating your own code language - you could implement the semantics of the code language however you want (such as a function being able to modify the scope of the caller), without necessarily having to do the same in the Python implementation of your language.